# What's the correct way of using logging functions with Unicode on PyQt5?

Tags: pyqt, pyqt5

The following code:

```py
from PyQt5.QtCore import qCritical

s = 'Negociação'
qCritical(s)
```

raises `UnicodeError`:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 7-8: ordinal not in range(128)
```

The [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtglobal.html#qCritical) of `qCritical()` for Qt C++ expects a `const char*`, so I think that's why PyQt5's `qCritical()` doesn't accept a plain `str`, even though its function signature takes a `str`.

Enconding it to UTF-8 works, although it returns a `bytes` object, not `str`:

```py
qCritical(s.encode('utf-8'))
```

Is it that the signature of `qCritical()` for PyQt5 is wrong or should I do it differently? Must I call `str.encode()` everytime I log a `str` that has unicode characters?

Comment: The documentation you linked explicitly says "The format should be a Latin-1 string." and shows that it uses utf8 conversion for non-latin characters. The signature is correct, as it refers to the basic usage. So, yes, you must use `s.encode()`.

Comment: Alright, but since passing a `str` may raise `UnicodeError`, the type hint could be `typing.Union[bytes, str]`. The distinction is clear on Qt C++ because they have `const char*` and `QString`, but PyQt5 uses `str` to refer to both of them. There's also no documentation for logging functions on PyQt5, so.

Comment: Do you know if there's any facility that prevents me from typing `str.encode()` throughout the whole code base where `qCritical()`, `qWarning()`, etc. are called? Something like Python's built-in `logging` library.

Comment: Maybe they changed the hint in PyQt6, in any case, you could always write an email to the [mailing list](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/mailman/listinfo/pyqt). And, no, I don't know about any alternatives, but you could always write a global function that does that automatically.

Comment: There's nothing special about the logging functions. PyQt treats most `const char*` parameters in the same way (e.g. [QImage](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qimage.html)). Accepting ascii-only `str` is simply a convenience that allows for [automatic conversions](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/gotchas.html#python-strings-qt-strings-and-unicode) where bytes are normally expected. I suppose the PyQt signature could be more accurate, but it's always wise check the Qt docs first rather than relying on the PyQt docs alone (which are still very much a work in progress).

Comment: PS: do you have a specific reason for using these functions (i.e. other than what is suggested in the Qt docs)? I've never used them myself, and I don't remember ever seeing any other PyQt code that does. More usually, people are looking for ways to disable these functions.

Comment: I don't have a specific reason. I just wanna do logging lol I would rather use Python's `logging`, but it makes sense to me to use Qt logging functions since I'm using the Qt framework. What would you advise for logging on Qt?